# Che cosa significa “e quando serve assolutamente senza” in questa frase?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

Non capisco bene l'uso del verbo "servire" nel brano sotto riportato. Si tratta di una descrizione dello stile di scrittura (oppure di dettatura) di Caterina da Siena (la descrizione riguarda le sue lettere, non *Il dialogo*). L'autore si riferisce alla tendenza di lei ad impiegare metafore in modo tale da evocare il linguaggio del Vangelo.

> Il suo modo di parlare e spiegare con le metafore e quando serve assolutamente senza, è semplicemente singolare e stupefacente.

Suppongo che la mia interpretazione sia la seguente: Il soggetto di "serve" è "modo di parlare e spiegare", "senza" si utilizza come avverbio e fa riferimento a "metafore", e il verbo "servire" vuol dire "bastare" o qualcosa di simile. L'autore quindi sembra dire che lui trova impressionante questa sua maniera di utilizzare metafore perfino quando potrebbe esprimersi adeguatamente senza ricorrere a tali figure retoriche.

Questa interpretazione vi sembra valida?

Comment: La mia interpretazione è che Caterina da Siena sappia spiegare le cose anche senza metafore se è veramente necessario.

Comment: Un caso di abuso di *assolutamente*. Si può dire *quasi senza*, ma *assolutamente senza* è, a mio parere, ridicolo. Fra l'altro, è anche sbagliato il “quando serve”: se serve, ci sono le metafore. Proposta di traduzione in italiano: "Il suo modo di parlare e, quando serve, spiegare con metafore è singolare e stupefacente.” (Anche *semplicemente* è del tutto inutile.) Si può sapere chi è l'autore?

Comment: Secondo me “assolutamente” è collegato a “serve”, cioè: “il suo modo di spiegare *con* le metafore e, quando proprio non se ne può fare a meno, *senza*”. Comunque tutta la frase è scritta male, come se fosse stata composta di getto senza rileggerla (già solo per le tre rime involontarie in -ente, oltre che per il nesso ambiguo a cui si riferisce la domanda).

Comment: @DaG: È quello che ho detto io.

Comment: @egreg: L'autore è Angelo Belloni. La frase è tratta da un'introduzione alle lettere di santa Caterina. A dire il vero, l'introduzione intera non sembra brillare per chiarezza, ma non essendo madrelingua non posso sempre distinguere un testo mal scritto da un lettore incompetente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scrive Baldini:

> Il linguaggio di santa Caterina è profondamente segnato dall'oralità e dalla colloquialità; le sue parole risultano più dette che dettate e le sue pagine presentano una metaforicità lavica. Lontana dalle norme stilistiche della retorica ciceroniana, che consigliava l'uso di una metafora «riservata» (*prudens*) e non «ardita», Caterina mostra piuttosto di prediligere  le metafore vive, audaci, assolute. È stato affermato che le metafore possono contenere o una mezza verità o una verità e mezza; ebbene nelle pagine di santa Caterina ci si imbatte frequentemente in metafore traboccanti di verità. Per santa Caterina la metofora non è un semplice ornamento, ma è destinata a provocare incrementi semantici, a fornire nuove informazioni, a generare nuove conoscenze. Le metafore sono per lei importanti e significativi strumenti cognitivi di cui si serve per rimediare a un vuoto di vocabolario. La ricchezza di allegorie e di metafore delle pagine cateriniane nasce anche da un bisogno di concretezza e scalda e colorisce la teoria, o l'esperienza della fede.

In considerazione del fatto che il linguaggio mistico si santa Caterina trasuda di metafore, credo che la frase dell'autore dovrebbe essere interpretata come

> Il suo modo di parlare e spiegare con le metafore e, *quando serve assolutamente*, senza, è semplicemente singolare e stupefacente.

ossia santa Caterina parla e spiega generalmente per metafore; solo quando non ne può fare a meno, *quando* (in quelle occasioni in cui...) *serve [assolutamente](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/assolutamente_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/)*, usa un linguaggio non metaforico.